# Observer scope can't use global variable

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private var Name = mutableListOf<String>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(repository)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    // viewmodel data

    setContent {
        SimpleStockInfoTheme {
            viewModel.getData().observe(this, Observer {
                Name.add(it)
                Log.d("EROR", Name.toString())
            })
            Log.d("EROR2", Name.toString())
                InfoCard(name = "dad", data = 1442.32 )


        }
    }
```

In Observer scope, global variable Name(mutableList) have a value (it). but outside of that, Name is empty List..
Why this situation happended??

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Thomas Sry bro I'll change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Observer scope, global variable Name(mutableList) have a value (it). but outside of that, Name is empty List

`Name` list is empty outside of the `observer` block because of the execution order of statements.

`Log` statement outside of the `observer` executes first, then the `Log` statement inside of the observer blog gets executed. What happens here is, all `Live Data` observers get registered first, and when the execution of synchronous code gets completed, after that the execution of observer code starts.

This goes for `suspending` functions too, they would only start executing after all synchronous code execution completes

Once `it` is added to the `Name` in the `observer` block, accessing `Name` after that won't return an `empty list`.

Comment: Could you help me more?

Comment: So as I understand, I think the code ( InfoCard~~) must be in Observer Scope. But InfoCard is composable. So I can't use it inside Observer. How can I change?

Comment: If you're observing live data changes inside composable, you should use observeAsState for live data change to perform recomposition. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/livedata/package-summary